# Convert date to time in some zone on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, datetime, time, timezone

I have 3 objects - @date, @time and @datetime. How to convert object @date to time (and to datetime) using zones from objects @time and @datetime?

Example:

```
@date = '2012-1-1'
@time = '2012-08-14 14:48:47 +1000'
@datetime = '2012-08-14 14:48:47 +0500'
@converted_date_to_time = ...     # should give '2012-1-1 00:00:00 +1000'
@converted_date_to_datetime = ... # should give '2012-1-1 00:00:00 +0500'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can parse a date like this

```
1.9.3p194> date = '2012-1-1'
=> "2012-1-1" 
1.9.3p194> Time.parse(date)
=> 2012-01-01 00:00:00 +1300
```

That is using my local timezone (Wellington, +13). You can also parse your time strings the same way

```
1.9.3p194> time = '2012-08-14 14:48:47 +1000'
=> "2012-08-14 14:48:47 +1000" 
1.9.3p194> Time.parse(time)
=> 2012-08-14 16:48:47 +1200
```

You will notice it looks a little wrong but that's because it is using my local timezone again, so it is accurate but currently in my timezone. You can then convert it to what ever timezone you want.

```
1.9.3p194> Time.parse(time).in_time_zone('Moscow')
=> Tue, 14 Aug 2012 08:48:47 MSK +04:00

1.9.3p194> Time.parse(time).in_time_zone('Brisbane')
=> Tue, 14 Aug 2012 14:48:47 EST +10:00
```

This will work the same for your `datetime` string as well.

If you want to use a specific timezone, you can do that as follows

```
1.9.3p194> Time.find_zone('Tokyo').parse('2012-08-14 14:48:47 +0500')
=> Tue, 14 Aug 2012 18:48:47 JST +09:00
```

Comment: this is correct, dont use '2012-1-1'.to_time.in_time_zone('Moscow'), but Time.parse('2012-1-1').in_time_zone('Moscow')

Answer (score 2):

If you want the time parsed in the zone specified in `config.time_zone`, you can use:

```
Time.zone.parse('2012-08-14 14:48:47 +1000')
```

I wouldn't use DateTime, though, unless you have some special requirements as the Time class now supports a huge range of dates and Rails handles time zones through Time.zone really well.